# How to use cron to run a php file?

Tags: php, cron

I'm using the cron job to run a php file that will update a text file.

[image]

the cron.php file contain

```
<?php


echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

$content = "some text here ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."\n";
$fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

I receive email every min contain the date. for here every things is cool.
**but the myText.txt in not changing**

Comment: Make sure the file has write permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File paths are relative to the *current working directory*. This is not necessarily the same as the directory that the PHP file is in. `"myText.txt"` may well refer to `/myText.txt` (the root directory) when executed as cron job without explicit working directory set, to which your script has no access rights.

Use *full file paths* like `"/home/thingsto/.../myText.txt"`, or `__DIR__ . '/myText.txt'`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the PHP is executed in a different  folder than your `myText.txt` when you're using cron job.

Either use absolute path to specify the text file's path;

or

change directory first (use a shell script to `cd` to your working directory and execute the PHP file). Run the shell script instead of the PHP file.

Answer (score -1):

try to specify the absolute path to the file "myText.txt". it looks like the script saves data to a wrong location.